# Handling master/slave database configuration in Rocket

Tags: database, rust, master-slave, rust-rocket

Rocket provides a way to [inject a database pool using guards](https://rocket.rs/guide/state/#databases), but I want to have a master/slave structure: 1 master for writing and 4 slaves for reading, with slaves selected at random.

I guess my routes function will look like

```
fn register_user_handler(
    conn: DbConnMaster,
    conn1: DbConnSlave1,
    conn2: DbConnSlave2,
    // ...
) {}
```

I have 5 such databases with a master/slave configuration, so around 25 connection pools. Specifying all those connections as guards in a handler seems verbose.

Is there a better way to keep those connection pool and use it across my application safely?

Comment: There's nothing to say you have to have a separate guard for every single  connection - instead of defining a type alias for your managed state, define it as a struct that contains all 25 of your pools. Then have your request guard return that instead.

Comment: Isn't this sort of abstraction usually handled at the DB level?

Comment: @JoeClay Thinking to do the same.